# What join in loop means in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
loop {
  Thread.start(@server.accept) do |client|
    @clients << client
    client.puts 'Connection established'
    listen_user_messages(client)
  end
}.join
```

What the join method does here? Is it required?

Comment: Did you read the official documentation ?

Comment: Calling `join` on a thread makes current thread wait for that one to finish. But since this `loop` will never return, `join` is useless here.

Comment: Is this from a tutorial? If so, is it possible to link to it?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev I think that we can use join only on the Thread ojects, not the loop method

Comment: @Andrew Grimm http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-tcp-chat/